# Graph with at least 2 degrees must contain a cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

In a non-empty graph where each vertex deg(v) ≥ 2, G must contain a cycle. I know this is true, but how would I prove this using induction?

Comment: I would like to see you giving it a try. Don't worry about making mistakes, just be sure that you understand the definitions and theory of the topics that you are studying. It will be easier for everyone here to help you understand things that now may seem difficult for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to prove directly: take a longest path, the endpoints have degree at least $2$ hence must be adjacent to some vertex already on the path, this looping back makes a cycle.

If you really want to prove this using induction, I suppose you can use the above as the base step and the inductive step directly gives you a cycle so I guess there's not much to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do induction on the number of edges:

If such a graph has a vertex $v$ of degree $2$, let $u,w$ be it’s neighbours. If there is an edge $ue$, we are done. Otherwise, remove $v$ and it’s two incident and add an edge $uw$. Apply the induction hypothesis to this graph and construct a cycle of the original graph by replacing $uw$ with $uvw$ if it occurs.

On the other hand, if all vertices have higher degree, remove one arbitrary edge and use the induction hypothesis again.

Comment: im sorry if this is a dumb question, but what would be the induction hypothesis in this case? and would the induction step be two cases then?